# Perform some task only for x time

Tags: python

I want to write a python function that when called should perform some task only for some time.

Example, when this function is called it should poll to the server for let's say 10 seconds and after 10 seconds it should exit.

I thought of doing it this way, but it doesn't seems appropriate. As obviously this function will take more than 10 seconds to do the job.

```
for i in range (0, 10):    # 10 seconds
    poll_to_server()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Can you suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to simply *not try again* after more than 10 seconds have elapsed? Then simply take a timestamp of the starting time and check if more than 10 seconds have elapsed. Or do you want to *cancel* any request that might be in flight after exactly 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the function `poll_to_server()` repeatedly for 10s, then you can do something like this

```
import time

t_end = time.time() + 10

while time.time() < t_end:
    poll_to_server()
```

Function `time.time` returns the current time in seconds since 1st Jan 1970. The value is in floating point, so you can even use it with sub-second precision. In the beginning the value `t_end` is calculated to be "now" + 10 seconds.

The loop will run until the current time exceeds this preset ending time.